# Cassandra Read a negative frame size (-2062548992)! error

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

I want to do OLAP calculation for JanusGraph through SparkGraphComputer, but I am now experiencing this error. Can anyone answer for me?

My storage backend is Cassandra, 40 million points and 120 million sides.

#### This is the configuration file.

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
gremlin.hadoop.graphReader=org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.cassandra.Cassandra3InputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.graphWriter=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoOutputFormat

gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true
gremlin.hadoop.inputLocation=none
gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output

janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=cql
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hostname=ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4...
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.port=9042
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.keyspace=probe
storage.cassandra.thrift.frame-size=4097

cassandra.input.partitioner.class=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

spark.master=local[4]
spark.executor.memory=1g
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.registrator=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.gryo.GryoRegistrator
```

#### This is wrong information.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2062548992)!
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getRangeMap(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:343)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:125)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.cassandra.CassandraBinaryInputFormat.getSplits(CassandraBinaryInputFormat.java:60)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.util.GiraphInputFormat.getSplits(GiraphInputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$2.apply(Partitioner.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$2.apply(Partitioner.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.reduceByKey(JavaPairRDD.scala:547)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkExecutor.executeVertexProgramIteration(SparkExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer.lambda$submitWithExecutor$1(SparkGraphComputer.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2062548992)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_local_ring(Cassandra.java:1318)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_local_ring(Cassandra.java:1305)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getRangeMap(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:335)
    ... 48
```

I hope someone can answer this question for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

9042 is the port for the cql native binary format not Thrift so the data coming over the wire doesnt match what thrift client expects. Thrift is port 9160, it is deprecated so make sure enabled in `cassandra.yaml` via `start_rpc`.

While you have it configured for CQL the getSplits call to thrift is being used (this is a very old mechanism to do this). The client should instead use the `system.size_estimates` with cql native table so thrift client can be removed. A good example is the spark client.

I would call this looks like a bug in janus graph, should open a ticket with them.

Comment: This is very helpful to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

at cassandra home,execute:

```sh
sh ./bin/cassandra -f
sh ./bin/nodetool enablethrift
```